# Meaning of "くらいいる"?

Tags: translation, particle-くらい

Read this sentence in an article. 
 https://woman.excite.co.jp/article/love/rid_Cafegoogirl_246784/

> アラサーにもなれば彼氏くらいいるものでしょ

Why is くらい used here? I've only seen くらい used when speaking about quantity. How does it function here?

Comment: Related (regarding くらい): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34132/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/63322/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38323/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「アラサーにもなれば彼氏{かれし}くらいいるものでしょ」

「くらい」, in this context, is nuanced.  It does not mean "approximately", which the word most often means.

Here. 「くらい」 means "***at least***" or "***at the very least***".

「いる」 means "***to have***", "***to possess***" here.

For the 「ものでしょ」 part, you may want to read:

[The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43083/the-meanings-of-%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a0/43127#43127)

It is the second usage (general tendency) in this sentence.

> "If you are around 30 (years old), you would probably have at least a boyfriend." or
>
> "If you are around 30, one would generally expect that you would have at least a boyfriend."

"a BF if not a husband" would be the implicit nuance.